# How to use parent template's properties in child template in EmberJS?

Tags: templates, ember.js, controller

I have a `/newLicense` route defined inside application route (`'/'`) as :

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('newLicense', {path: '/newLicense'});
});
```

I have a property in application controller called `is_admin` which gets set properly every time the application controller is called. Now in `newLicense` template, I want to show a message based on whether logged in user is admin or not (which is stored in `is_admin` of application controller).

I tried

```
{{#if is_admin}}
    <p> You are logged in as Admin user. </p>
{{else}}
    <p> You are logged in as Read-Only user. </p>
{{/if}}
```

But it's not working. I also tried to provide application controller in `newLicenseController` as :

```
App.newLicenseController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
});
```

But it's still not working. Then I tried `{{#if application.is_admin}}` still no luck.

Any help on this concept is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. It was a simple mistake. One should access the properties of controllers listed in needs as : {{controllers.controller_name.property_name}}.

So in this case, it would become :

```
{{#if controllers.application.is_admin}}
    <p> You are logged in as Admin user. </p>
{{else}}
    <p> You are logged in as Read-Only user. </p>
{{/if}}
```